# Passenger 3 with Rails 3 doesn't load gems from vendor/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I've setup a new environment with Ruby 1.9.2 and Passenger 3. A Rails 3 app is deployed with Capistrano. RAILS_ENV is set to staging.

When trying to boot the application, Passenger complains about a missing gem. Running

```
bundle --deployment
```

installs gems to RAILS_ROOT/vendor, but doesn't solve the error.

If I install the missing gem as a system gem (eg. sudo gem install), the error disappears but now the next gem in the Gemfile is reported as missing.

I could solve this by installing my gems to the system, but I'd like to understand why installing them to the vendor directory isn't working. My understanding is that the idea of bundler is to avoid having to keep all gems installed to the system.

I have RAILS_ROOT/.bundle/config set to:

```
BUNDLE_FROZEN: "1"
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, gems should remain in a consistent location to avoid them being reinstalled every deploy. Therefore, try removing `BUNDLE_PATH` from your config (default location is `~/.bundle`).

I'm not sure what `bundle --deployment` does (I couldn't see mention of this in the docs). I use something like this command in my deploy scripts:

```
after :'deploy:update_code' do
  run "cd #{release_path} && bundle install --without test cucumber development"
end
```

Comment: I can what you're suggesting. I'll try that, but I guess my original questions remains: why doesn't Passenger pickup the gems in vendor/bundle ?

The --deployment flag is documented (and recommended) on the Bundler site at http://gembundler.com/rationale.html#deploying-your-application

Comment: Thanks for the link (odd there's no mention of it in `bundle --help`). Why do you believe the issue is with passenger? Have you tried loading script/console on your server?